# Form mailto problem with image button in FireFox & Chrome appends x= y=

Tags: forms, firefox, google-chrome, imagebutton, mailto

When I use mailto with a form image button in FireFox or Chrome I get "x=101 y=15" type text added to the end of the body text. The x & y values vary each time.

A regular submit button works fine. IE (for once) gets it right.

Is something wrong with my code?

The example below has a normal submit button and an image button.

```
<form action="mailto:example@gmail.com?subject=my subject line&body=my body text" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
<input type="submit" value="Thank you.">
<input type="image" src="image1.png"  onmouseover="this.src='image2.png';"   onmouseout="this.src='image1.png';" alt="Submit"> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is by design.

When the user clicks an image button, the browser sends the coordinates that he clicked on to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys. I went with a **BUTTON** tag solution to avoid the x= y= issue - but had to use CSS to hide the default button:

```
<form action="mailto:example@gmail.com?subject=my subject line&body=my body text" method="post" enctype="text/plain"  >
<button type="submit" style= "background-color:#ffffff; border:0px; margin:0px;">
<img src="image1.png" onmouseover="this.src='image2.png';" onmouseout="this.src='image1.png';" alt=""/>
</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

From [w3 specs](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_8.html#SEC8.1.2.5):

> An INPUT element with `TYPE=IMAGE'
>   specifies an image resource to
>   display, and allows input of two form
>   fields: the x and y coordinate of a
>   pixel chosen from the image. The names
>   of the fields are the name of the
>   field with`.x' and `.y' appended.`
>   TYPE=IMAGE' implies `TYPE=SUBMIT'
>   processing; that is, when a pixel is
>   chosen, the form as a whole is
>   submitted.

Perhaps working fine in IE in your case, but not as intended.